# PC Case is getting hot but sensors read low

Tags: motherboard, cooling, overheating

When my computer is under load for a long time, for example playing BFV for 1-2 hours, it gets real hot. When I touch the case externally (behind of CPU) it's unusually hot. It shut down once due to high temp (I'm guessing) and didn't boot up again until it's cooled off.

This started to happen 2 weeks ago, up until then I had no issues and were able to play BFV or similar games with silent fan profile without any heating issues.

When I take reading from CPU, GPU, Motherboard, Water Cooler etc. everything is within or under limits.

I had XMP (Asus auto overclocking) profile in motherboard and Asus AI Suite. Loaded optimized defaults in mobo and uninstalled Asus AI Suite just in case.

However it's still same ( I feel like it's better but still gets unusually hot). I know airflow in the case is good, it's been good for over a year now.

When I physically touched motherboard, CPU water cooler and other places within the case they are not hot.

Considering nothing has changed and all the sensors read well, fan design (air flow) works well, what can be the problem?

- 14-Core Intel Core i9-7940X, 2200 MHz (22 x 100)
- Motherboard Name Asus ROG Strix X299-E Gaming
- X299-E Gaming Corsair 32GB RAM RTX 2080 Ti
- Corsair Water Cooler

Comment: Your assessment of airflow within the PC case is apparently not accurate.  The airflow seems adequate where the fans are drawing air and blowing, but deadzones exist where hot air accumulates.

Comment: @sawdust So why do you think this has happened after 1 year? I just assumed if airflow was bad it would be bad from the day 1. Isn't that the case?